# resize window with user script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How do you resize current Chrome or Firefox window from Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script. I tried

```
window.resizeTo(1000, 500);
```

, but it doesn't work for some reason.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this demo on w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_resizeto)

> [Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo):
>
> - You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.
> - You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than
>     one tab.

Comment: Tried that before I posted my question. The code only works for newly created window. For the current window, it fails.